# Cast parent to its child

Tags: java, oop

I have:

```
class A
{
     public String getID() { return "id of A";}
}

class B extends A
{ 
     public String getID() { return "id of B"; }
}
```

and

```
class C {
 public A returnA() { 
    return new A(); 
  } 
}
```

Now I somehow need to do:

```
C c = new C();
B b = (B)c.returnA(); 
String id = b.getId();
```

But I don't have access to implementation of `C.returnA()`, and I can't change return type of it to B.

Comment: C doesn't extend A therefore you won't be able to cast A to C

Comment: You're not trying to cast a child to its parent - you're trying to cast a parent (`A`) to the child (`B`). That's clearly not going to work.

Comment: c.returnA() returns A, You can't cast to B. ClassCastException will be thrown

Comment: There isn't a mechanism to automatically morph an instance of the superclass (`A`) into an instance of the subclass (`B`).

Comment: sorry renamed it to Cast parent to its children

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are casting a parent into a children.
You can never do that, because `new A()` is absolutely not a `B`.

Consider this: `String extends Object`. Now try to cast `(String) new Object()`. It wouldn't make any sense at all.

Because your object is not a `B` anyway, there is no way it could have the behavior of B.

What you want here is use a Decorator Pattern. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern

Here is an example of what a implementation of a Decorator could be:

```
public class B extends A {

    private A decorated;
    public B(A decorated) {
        this.decorated = decorated;
    }

    @Override
    public String getID() {
        return "id of B";
    }

    @Override
    public void otherMethodOfA() {
        return decorated.otherMethodOfA();
    }
}
```

Note that it is mandatory to override all methods of A to make sure you call the method on the decorated element. (here `otherMethodOfA` is an example)

Use like this:

```
C c = new C();
B b = new B(c.returnA());
String id = b.getID();
```

Comment: @Stanislav: As for the decorator, if you give more details about what functionalities of B you need, I can help with the implementation.

Comment: @njzk2 I edited the question and this is the simplified version of what I need to achieve. But if you can show a small example of how I can cast c.returnA(); to a custom class that will overwrite getID function that would be great.

Comment: @Stanislav: there you go.

Comment: Wait a second. `Object` is the parent class of all classes. I can put a `String` into an `Object` and then cast the `Object` into `String`: `Object ob = "Hello";String obStr = (String) ob;` and it would compile just fine. It's basically the same situation: a parent is cast into child, but it seems to only work with Object->Any other class, while doesn't work with custom classes.

Comment: @parsecer in the case of the OP's question, it would be as doing this: `Object o = new Object(); String str = (String) o;` `o` was never a `String` to being with, so the cast doesn't make sense

Comment: @njzk2 I see. I didn't think the compiler would know *what* would get assigned to `Object`. So, would a OP's method work correctly if the `returnA()` method returned `new B()`?

Comment: @parsecer The compiler doesn't know what exact instance an object is, it only knows what type the variable declares, that's why casting is sometimes necessary. The OP's example compiles, but throws an exception at runtime. Also, yes `A returnA() { return new B();}` and then `(B) returnA();` works fine, just as in your String/Object example

Answer (score 0):

That won't work.  `c.returnA()` returns an `A`.  An `A` is *not* a `B`.  (A `B` *is* an `A`, but that's not relevant here).

Answer (score -1):

The answer of [njzk2](http://#answer-24957686) is perfect. Anyway, if you ended up reading this post and like me, you don't like overriding every method, you can just do this:

```
public class B extends A {

    public B(A nonDecorated) {
        this.anotherValueOfA = nonDecorated.getAnotherValueOfA();
    }

    @Override
    public String getID() {
        return "id of B";
    }
}
```

There is no need to override every method and the object is constructed with the values from its parent.

This is, of course, assuming class A is:

```
class A {
    private int anotherValueOfA;
    public String getID() {return "id of A";}
    public int getAnotherValueOfA() {return this.anotherValueOfA;}
}
```